# Difficult calculus 2 question on using the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have about 5 questions of the same kind that I have no idea how to solve, the title of the work sheet is fundamental theorem of calculus.

the image of the question :

[the questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV9S0.jpg)

Comment: So the fundamental theorem of calculus is about differentiating an integral. Have you ever seen a technique for computing limits by taking derivatives? Also: you can enter a description of the image in the spot where it says "enter image description here."

Comment: Please see how to properly format your questions.  Furthermore, recall L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: i havent seen a  technique for computing limits by taking derivatives.

but im pretty sure thats what they want me to do.

and   L'Hopital's i need to derive both parts but its only if they both have the same limit 0 or infinity isnt it ?

Comment: You haven't seen a method of finding limits with derivatives but you are familiar with L'Hospitals rule? That seems very contradicting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you are asked to evaluate
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}\int_0^x \frac{t}{\cos t}dt
$$
An integral that looks like $\int_a^af(t)dt$ evaluates to 0, because we are measuring the area under a function over a zero length interval. Then, since $\sin^2 (x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ we can see that this is an indeterminate form, and we can apply l'hospital's.

Here is where the FTC comes in. Note that by the FTC
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x \frac{t}{\cos t}dt=\frac{x}{\cos x}
$$
So by l'hospital's rule
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}\int_0^x \frac{t}{\cos t}dt=
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\sin(x)\cos x}\frac{x}{\cos x}=\\
\frac{1}{2}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)\cos^2 x}
$$
And applying L'Hospital's again
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)\cos^2 x}=
\frac{1}{2}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\cos(x)\cos^2 x-2\sin x \cos x}=1/2
$$
Since we have arrived at a continuous function through our work. The rest should be similar.

Comment: thank you very very much i understand now !

Comment: of course! Also, notice that in the second problem there is a very nasty integral to actually compute, which should also hint you want to get rid of that integral. p.s. Be sure to accept if you're question is answered, so people know your question is answered (and so my day gets brighter)

Comment: i never posted here before but i pressed the little check mark i hope that means i accepted it